# Jenkins plugin jacoco for code coverage doesn't consider classes exculded from build.gradle in report

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, jacoco

Here is part of my build.gradle which I have configured to exclude the classes from code coverage.

```
test {
    jacoco {
        append = false        
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco/jacoco.exec")           
    }   
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport 
}
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml {
            enabled true 
        }
        html {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it,
                    exclude: ['**/*DAO*.*'])
        })
    }
}
```

Here I want to exclude DAO classes in my project, as I am mocking those classes anyways, and I am planning to cover them in DB test cases differently from Unit testing.

When I run below command:
 gradle jacocoTestReport

It generates the code coverage report which excludes those classes from code coverage,
${project_dir}\build\reports\jacoco\test\html\index.html

As a reason I have excluded those from gradle build via:

```
 afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it,
                    exclude: ['**/*DAO*.*'])
        })
    }
```

But when Jenkins builds the project the code coverage reports generated by jenkins doesn't consider this settings, and the report which is generated by jenkins includes those classes, in coverage report.

Another work around I have tried is to modify the code configuration from 'Post-build Actions' for jacoco plugin in jenkins 
I have set my pattern under Exclusions `(e.g.: **/*DAO*.*)` text field, and this is working fine, test cases are getting excluded from code coverage.

But I wanted to know that is there any way I can avoid configuring jenkins for specifing exclusion patterns and uses the reports genrated by gradle jacocoTestReport on jenkins, because this redudant because I am specifing it in build.gradle and If I have to create multiple branches on jenkins then It is kind of maintainance as well.

According to below post this issue is not yet resolved
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15570

Is any one has idea on this?

Note: My Jacoco version is :

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"
}
```

and Jacoco plugins version on jenkins is :

```
2.0.1
```